# protractor-html-screenshot-reporter not showing all the tests executed in the reporter file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Am trying to run firsttest.js:

```
// firsttest.js
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  var firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));
  var secondNumber = element(by.model('second'));
  var goButton = element(by.id('gobutton'));
  var latestResult = element(by.binding('latest'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
  });

  it('should have a title', function() {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
  });

  it('should add one and two', function() {

    firstNumber.sendKeys(1);
    secondNumber.sendKeys(2);

    goButton.click();

    expect(latestResult.getText()).toEqual('3');
  });

  it('should add four and six', function() {
    // Fill this in.
    expect(latestResult.getText()).toEqual('10');
  });

  it('test1', function() {
    // Fill this in.
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('test2', function() {
    // Fill this in.
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('test3', function() {
    // Fill this in.
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

conf file:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['firsttest.js'],
  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  }],
  onPrepare: function() {
    // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/screnshots`:
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
      baseDirectory: './e2e-reports',
      takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
      docTitle: 'Pytheas Tests'
    }));
  }
}
```

Console o/p:

> Failures:
>
> 1) angularjs homepage should add four and six    Message:
>        Expected '0' to equal '10'.    Stacktrace:
>        Error: Failed expectation
>       at [object Object]. (/Users/bgowda1/Work/Projects/Demos/protractor-tests/firsttest.js:35:36)
>
> Finished in 6.191 seconds 6 tests, 6 assertions, 1 failure

HTML report shows only 5 tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce it - this is always the latest `it` block that is missing in the final HTML report. This should be reported to the [protractor-html-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/issues) bug tracker.

As a current workaround, downgrade to protractor 1.4.0 (tested, worked for me). Or, add an empty `it()` block to the end of the file. I'll update the post if I'll come up with a fix, or better workaround.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I downgraded protractor version to 1.4.0 it works.